# Missing gmp-arm.h in Centos GMP Development Tools

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, centos, gmp

I'm working on a cross compile of GCC for the ARM architecture, which requires...among other things...GMP headers and libraries.

I'm working on CentOS 7.2, so I installed the development tools for GMP (gmp-devel), only to find that the header I needed...gmp-arm.h...is not included, as per the error thrown by configure

```
/usr/include/gmp.h:37:21: fatal error: gmp-arm.h: No such file or directory
```

#include "gmp-arm.h"

I can't find this header *anywhere*, nor can I find any package for CentOS that contains it.  This is driving me insane...any ideas where I can find this header or if it's just a bug or mistaken error?

**NOTE:**  In response to comment #1, I have a cross compiler that I set up by running the standalone toolchain script from the NDK.  I'm using it to build a GCC compiler that will run on an arm-android device.

**CLARIFICATION:** I *originally*ran the top level gcc configure specifying --host=x86_64-linux-gnu and --target=arm-linux-androideabi.  It was this configure that *originally*failed.

I then re-ran configure specifying --host=arm-linux-androideabi and --target=arm-linux-androideabi.  The missing gmp-arm.h error does occur, but further into the build (see comments #2/#3)

Comment: Could you be clearer about what kind of cross-compiler you want? If you want the compiler to run on a PC and produce code for something else, you should not need gmp-arm.h. Which `configure` complained about missing that header?

Comment: Added details in comments.  As an FYI, I re-ran configure using --host=arm-linux-androideabi and --target=arm-linux-androideabi, but that causes a different gmp.h error to show up later on in the build  (conftest.c:47:17: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
 #include "gmp.h")

Comment: Additionally...linking gmp.h to the mpfr directory causes a recurrence of the gmp-arm.h error.

Comment: "that will run on an arm-android" vs --host=x86_64-linux-gnu : sorry, it doesn't make sense. Please try to clarify your message again...

Comment: Message clarified.  I also came up with a workaround but I'm waiting to see if the binaries run correctly before posting it

Comment: The workaround I employed was to download sources for gmp, mpfr and mpc, cross-compile them for android and install them to the to-be cross-compiled GCC directory.